# Can't fetch data do Gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to retrive a dataset to a Gridview, but I just don't get any row in my Gridview. What am I doing wrong?

the page code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CType(Master, AreaTrabalho).AlteraTitulo = "Projectos"

    Using oSQL As New clsSQL(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString1"))
        If oSQL.OpenConnection Then
            oSQL.ToDataGrid(Me.GridView1, "Select * from users")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

the class functions used to fetch data

```
Public Function ToDataGrid(ByVal oDataGrid As GridView, _
                           ByVal sQuery As String, _
                  Optional ByVal sTable As String = "") As Boolean
    Try

        Dim objDataSet As New Data.DataSet
        'Preenche o dataset
        objDataSet = ToDataSet(sQuery, sTable)

        oDataGrid.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables(0)

        objDataSet.Dispose()
        objDataSet = Nothing

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent OnError("ToDataGrid", ex)
    End Try
End Function

Public Function ToDataSet(ByVal sQuery As String, Optional ByVal sTable As String = "") As Data.DataSet
    Try

        m_objCommand = New SqlCommand(sQuery, m_objConnection)

        Dim objDataSet As New Data.DataSet
        Dim objSqlDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(m_objCommand)

        'Verifica se foi defenido a tabela
        If sTable = "" Then
            objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet)
        Else
            objSqlDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, sTable)
        End If

        objSqlDataAdapter.Dispose()
        objSqlDataAdapter = Nothing

        Return objDataSet
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent OnError("ToDataSet", ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling [the Databind method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.databind.aspx) on the GridView after setting the datasource in your ToDataGrid method:

```
oDataGrid.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a webforms application, which if it is the case, you need to call `GridView.DataBind()` after you set the datasource to bind the data to the grid.